# How to programmatically determine if an image file is georeferenced

Tags: c#, wpf, image, esri-arc-engine

I have a task to programamatically scan a folder for georeferenced images. There might be a lot of images, some quite large, and some not georeferenced. The spatial information can also be either embedded or in a world file.

How can I tell programmatically (C#/WPF/ESRI Runtime) if "C:\someFolder\file.x" is georeferenced?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First check the file type to see if it's a format that supports built in georeferencing (GeoTiff, jp2, and MrSid). Other static image files would need some sort of companion file with the georeferencing information. So for each image file you'd want to look for a matching companion file.

If you add some info on what formats the images/world files are in it'll be easier to show you some sample code.